# Compare method with generics

Tags: java, generics, compare

well this is my problem:
I'm using a class ArrayLinearList to create diferent array types. Now, I have to create a boolean method: compare(Linearlist other) and LinearList is an interface for ArrayLinearList.

When I use compare, this method is supossed to return false if the compared elements are different. But I don't know how to do it work, cause the argument other of the element are an Interface, and the array to compare is a T[] array type so when I use the method should look like this:
element.compare(other);

So how can I convert a LinearList object, where LinearList is an interface, to an object of t[] type??

```
public boolean compare(LinearList other){
ArrayLinearList<T> element2 = other;
// cast try:

 Integer size1 = other.size();
 Integer size2 = 0;


 for (int  i = 0; i< size; i++) 
  size2++;

    if (size2 == size1) 
      return true;
        else return false;

//else return false;

}
```

then I get this error:`error: incompatible types: LinearList<CAP#1> cannot be converted to ArrayLinearList<T>
    ArrayLinearList<T> element2 = other;
                                  ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in class ArrayLinearListTaller1
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
1 error`

SO, how can I convert other to a element type T[], or how can I compare them??

If someone can help me, I would be very grateful¡¡¡ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration should be or `public boolean compare(LinearList<? extends T> other)`, so that the compiler knows that the objects that it's retrieving from `other` will be of type `T` or a subtype thereof.

Comment: I've already try it, and when I try something like this: 
`other = (T[]) new Object[capacity];`
supposing that other is now recognized as type T but doing this I get this:
 error: incompatible types: T[] cannot be converted to LinearList<? extends T>
     otro = (T[]) new Object[initialCapacity];

Comment: Sure, because an array is not a `LinearList`.  Do you have a suitable constructor in your `ArrayLinearList` class that you can use for this?

Comment: you mean this constructor?
`public ArrayLinearList(int initialCapacity)
   {
      if( initialCapacity < 1 )
         throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ( "initialCapacity must be >= 1" );
      element = ( T[] ) new Object[ initialCapacity ];
      size = 0;
   }`

Comment: No, I meant one where you pass in an array, and assign it directly to `element`.

Comment: I only have this two constructors in ArrayLinearList:
`public ArrayLinearListTaller1( int initialCapacity ){
   protected T[] element;  // array of elements
   protected int size;   // number of elements in array 

     if( initialCapacity < 1 )
         throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ( "initialCapacity must be >= 1" );
      element = ( T[] ) new Comparable[ initialCapacity ];
      size = 0;
   }

   public ArrayLinearListTaller1( ){
      this( 10 );

   }`

Comment: Are you allowed to add another one?

Comment: Actually, backtrack a moment.  Why are you doing `other = (T[]) new Object[capacity];` anyway?  If you're doing a `compare`, you shouldn't be changing `other`.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, you have reason. And yes I'm allowed to add another. 
But for example, if I do this: if(element[0] == other[0]), it should works and compare the elements if other were recognized as type T, but I get this:
 `error: array required, but LinearList<CAP#1> found
     if(element[0] == other[0])`

Comment: Instead of writing `other[0]`, write `other.get(0)`, assuming that such a method exists in your `LinearList` interface (which it kind of needs to, or the interface will be more-or-less unusable).